# Why is the Linear Layout not visible in my AVD?

Tags: android

I tried to understand why my LinearLayout is not appearing in the AVD but nothing is working.. Please view my snapshot for more details and let me know if i'm making any mistake. I deleted the part of the relative layout present in this program for a less messy question code to debug

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="233dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_small"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_big"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Big" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constraint to `LinearLayout` cause they are ignored
 remove

```
 tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
```

To see the missing constraints,
every View needs to be constrained at least with two constraints (one for the vertical axis, one for the horizontal axis).

Comment: Hey. I changed the code to
`<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="233dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">`
and still not working dunno where's the problem

Comment: remove bottomConstraint and every thing should work fine

Comment: and make sure the View(under linearLayout ) is not covering the Linear layout, you can try to hide it for testing .

Comment: The view of the Relative Layout was covering the Linear Layout yes

Answer (score 0):

add/replace this in your code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="233dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/other_layout"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_small"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_big"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Big" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

in your code u haven't give the constraints value so, whenever you tried to run your code in your emulator or device the layout wraps to 0,0.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code but 
`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/other_layout"`
was showing errors and the linear layout is still not appearing in AVD? Do you think i have to install something to make it work?